# Recurrence relations for series question

Tags: combinatorics

I've got stuck on the following question (sorry for my English):

What is the number of series in length n (n greater than 2) from the group {0,1,2,3,4} which the subtraction between two following members in absolute value
is 1. The question guided to come up with a recurrence relation for every possible ending for a series in length n and use the mutuality between them to solve the problem.

The recurrence relations I came up with are:

0, $a_n$ = $a_{n-1}$

1, $a_n$ = $2a_{n-1}$

2, $a_n$ = $2a_{n-1}$

3, $a_n$ = $2a_{n-1}$

4, $a_n$ = $a_{n-1}$

I don't know how to go on from here, I have no idea how to combine them into 1 recurrence relation so I can solve it for the general $a_n$

Later I came up with a new recurrence relation for 0 and 4:

$a_n$ = $2a_{n-2}$

Since there is only one number before them and for it there is 2 options to come before it.

But I still got stuck.

Can somebody tell me how to combine the recurrence relations into one?

Comment: You certainly can't have $a_n=a_{n+1}=2a_{n+1}$ since $a_{n+1}$ may not be $0$.

Comment: I know, that's why I got stuck.

Comment: You need to give different names to each of the cases. Like, $a_n$ is the number of sequences ending in zero, $b_n$ is the number of sequences ending in $1$, etc. Then the equations you get are $a_n=b_{n-1}$, $b_{n}=a_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$, etc. This gives a mutual recurrence with $5$ unknowns. You can simplify this to three unknowns by exploiting the symmetry of the problem; group sequences which end in $0$ and $4$ together, and same for $1$ and $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let

- $a_n$ be the number of sequences ending with either $0$ or $4$.
- $b_n$ be the number of sequences ending with either $1$ or $3$.
- $c_n$ be the number of sequences ending with either $2$.

Show that
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{l}
a_n = b_{n-1},
\\
b_{n} = a_{n-1}+2c_{n-1} ,
\\
c_n = b_{n-1}.
\end{array}
\end{align}
Use this to solve for $a_n,b_n$ and $c_n$ individually. The answer is $a_n+b_n+c_n$. You will need to split into cases based on whether $n$ is even or odd.